# woocommerce add text to specific email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I had asked this before but unfortunately I realized that the answer given did not work, so I am asking again:

I am trying to add some text to the customer-order-processing email from `WooCommerce`, and it should ONLY be added in this particular email and ONLY if chosen payment method is `Paypal`. I have come so far as the text is added, and only when Paypal is chosen as payment method, but the text is displayed in every email to the customer now, for example also in the order-completed email or customer-note email. I have the following:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table','add_order_email_instructions', 0, 2);
            function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {
        if ( 'paypal' == $order->payment_method && ! $sent_to_admin ) {
            echo 'my text:';
        } 
}
```

I have tried with additional conditionals, like ! `$order->has_status( 'processing' )`, but nothing is working. Any help?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a way to tell which email ID/type you are on while you are on it. I feel like I've looked at this before but run into trouble when trying to patch WooCommerce.

Comment: I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/pull/9485) that may make it possible in the future. If it is not accepted them you must override the `customer-order-processing.php` template.

Comment: Thank you, I hope it will get accepted!

Comment: It was merged, so it is in the master branch at github, but not sure when it will be officially released.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to only add a note to emails that had a status of "on-hold" and sent to admins (not customers). This worked well for me:

```
/* Add manual processing note to new orders to admin */
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details','add_order_email_instructions', 10, 4 );
function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( $order->status == 'on-hold' && $sent_to_admin ) {
        echo '<p><strong>Note: Manual processing for this order is required.</strong></p>';
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ops... I don't know why I thought your email was not firing at all.

By the way, if you wanna add that text only to specific email template, there are 2 ways:

1. harder one: disable 'customer-order-processing' and create your own email template. You can start by this tutorial: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/
2. easier one and **recommended**: override 'customer-order-processing.php' and add some code in that template.

This are the steps:

- go in WooCommerce -> Settings -> Email -> Processing Order and click 'Copy files to theme'.
- if it doesn't exist, a 'woocommerce' folder will be created in your theme folder and you will find the template file in woocommerce -> emails
- open 'customer-processing-order.php' and add needed code where you prefer:

  ```
  if( 'paypal' == $order->payment_method ) {
   echo 'my text:';
  }
  ```

Code is not tested but should work!

Good luck ;)

Comment: Changing the priority doesn't effect how the conditional for which email type this is.

Comment: you right! I don't know why I thought email was not firing at all! Just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that my patch should be available with **WooCommerce 2.5**. When it is, then the `$email` object will be available on the `woocommerce_email_before_order_table` hook (and on other hooks in the emails) and you will be able to test the `$email->id` for specific emails. Something like the following in your `functions.php` (or preferably in a plugin) should do it:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table','add_order_email_instructions', 10, 4 );
function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( 'customer_processing_order' == $this->id && 'paypal' == $order->payment_method && ! $sent_to_admin ) {
        echo 'my text:';
    } 
}
```

Comment: Great! Do you know when 2.5 will be released?

Comment: no, i don't. in the meantime, @FrancescoCarlucci's answer #2 should work.

Comment: I am using `add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table','add_order_email_instructions', 10, 4 );
function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( 'customer_processing_order' == $order->get_id() && ! $sent_to_admin ) {
        echo 'Your login details are on their way. (They may take up to 10 minutes to arrive in your inbox.';
    } 
}` in WooCommerce 3+ now as $this->id would not fly and $order->get_id() did. Only the message is still not added to the block with "Your order .. received and is now being processed. " Ideas?

Comment: `if ( $email->id == 'customer_processing_order' )...` worked in the end